# Pandas - match a column of string with a column of regular expressions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The problem: I have two dataframes - one with a bunch of product titles that are not normalized, and one with a bunch of regular expressions that are tied to normalized product titles. I need to match the non-normalized titles to some regular expressions which are tied to normalized titles. 
It should make more sense with the sample data below.

First dataframe (raw_titles):

```
|   | Title                                          | Release Date |
|---|------------------------------------------------|--------------|
| 1 | Apple iPad Air (3rd generation) - 64GB         | 01/01/20     |
| 2 | Philips Hue White Ambiance A19 LED Smart Bulbs | 08/12/20     |
| 3 | Powerbeats Pro Totally Wireless Earphones      | 06/20/19     |
```

Second dataframe (regex_titles):

```
|   | Regex                                                 | Manufacturer | Model                   |
|---|-------------------------------------------------------|--------------|-------------------------|
| 1 | /ipad\s?air(?=.*(\b3\b|3rd\s?gen|2019))|\bair\s?3\b/i | Apple        | iPad Air (2019)         |
| 2 | /hue(?=.*cher)/i                                      | Philips      | Hue White Ambiance Cher |
| 3 | /powerbeats\s?pro/i                                   | Beats        | Powerbeats Pro          |
```

The idea is to take each title in raw_titles, and run it through all the values in regex_titles to see if there's a match. Once that's done, raw_titles should then have two additional columns, Manufacturer and Model, which correspond to the regex_titles series they matched to (if there was no match, it would just stay empty.

Then the final table would look like this:

```
|   | Title                                          | Release Date | Manufacturer | Model           |
|---|------------------------------------------------|--------------|--------------|-----------------|
| 1 | Apple iPad Air (3rd generation) - 64GB         | 01/01/20     | Apple        | iPad Air (2019) |
| 2 | Philips Hue White Ambiance A19 LED Smart Bulbs | 08/12/20     |              |                 |
| 3 | Powerbeats Pro Totally Wireless Earphones      | 06/12/19     | Beats        | Powerbeats Pro  |
```

Comment: So `len(raw_titles) == len(regex_titles)`?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with the final desired result. Not looking for length matching, but actual matching using a table of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest is to test each of the regexes on each of the titles and return the first match you find. First, we'll define a function that will return two values: the manufacturer and model of the regex row, if we match, two `None`s otherwise:

```
def find_match(title_row):
    for _, regex_row in regex_titles.iterrows():
        if re.search(regex_row['Regex'], title_row['Title']):
            return [regex_row['Manufacturer'], regex_row['Model']]
    return  [None, None]
```

Then we'll apply our function to our titles dataframe and save the output to two new columns, Manufacturer and Model:

```
raw_titles[['Manufacturer', 'Model']] = raw_titles.apply(find_match, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')

                                            Title Release Date Manufacturer            Model
0          Apple iPad Air (3rd generation) - 64GB     01/01/20        Apple  iPad Air (2019)
1  Philips Hue White Ambiance A19 LED Smart Bulbs     08/12/20         None             None
2       Powerbeats Pro Totally Wireless Earphones     06/20/19        Beats   Powerbeats Pro
```

One complication is that you'll have to translate your perl regexes into the python regex format:

perl: `/powerbeats\s?pro/i` -> python: `(?i)powerbeats\s?pro`

They're mostly the same, with a few small differences. [Here's the reference.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: That error means the dataframe you're applying the function to doesn't have a `Title` column. Are you applying the function to the right dataframe?

Comment: Yup, and if I just print(title_row), instead of the if statement, it works (prints out the all contents of each row). However, if I try print(title_row['Title']) or any other column name, it gives the key error.

Comment: You cannot call that function directly on the title dataframe, you must call it on a _row_ of the title dataframe. e.g. `raw_titles.apply(find_match, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')`

Comment: What I mean is I do raw_titles.apply, but then in the find_match function, instead of the if re.search..., I just put print(title_row['Title']) and it will still give the same key error. However if I just print(title_row) there, it'll show all the data for that row, including the Title.

Comment: Add the output of `raw_titles.columns`, `raw_titles.dtypes`, and `raw_titles.shape` to your question.